# Showing green lines at right and bottom of recorded video using GPUImage2

Tags: swift3, gpuimage, photosframework

I am using example from path: **GPUImage2-master/examples/iOS/SimpleVideoRecorder GPUImage2**

It records proper video and saving the file in camera roll without green lines using provided code in sample.

**Issue 1:**
Now, I have changed some properties in ViewController.swift like

```
AVCaptureSessionPreset640x480 to AVCaptureSessionPresetHigh

 Size(width:480, height:640) to Size(width:Float(UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width), height:Float(UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height))
```

and saved the video to camera roll. It saved properly. But the issue is, showing green lines at right and bottom of the recorded video and start playing with black shadow over video (in the first frame).
Why video is showing green lines.

**Issue 2:**
Now changed

```
camera = try Camera(sessionPreset:AVCaptureSessionPreset640x480)
```

to

```
camera = try Camera(sessionPreset:AVCaptureSessionPresetHigh, cameraDevice: nil, location: .frontFacing, captureAsYUV: true)
```

It inverts video camera to 180 degrees and also records video inverted.

Please help, I want to record video of device size.

**Updated ViewController file:** https://www.dropbox.com/s/ysadca77wxvw6wx/ViewController.swift?dl=0 
**Recorded video green lines URL:** https://www.dropbox.com/s/g43ic3cxyl3h62f/test.mp4?dl=0
**Inverted Recorded video URL:** https://www.dropbox.com/s/2cu4me3zlqpj4ix/test%202.mp4?dl=0